# Deactivate thermostat

Tags: wiring, thermostat

I have a roommate that constantly turns the thermostat down to 65 during the winter months. Is there a way I can deactivate it, while maintaining a comfortable 72?

Comment: put on a sweater

Comment: All joking aside don't look for a technical solution for a social problem; talk to the guy and reach a compromise you both agree to.

Comment: you could add a lock box, which would restrict access to only you/people with a key.

Comment: I agree with the lockbox idea, but if they are roommates then the other guy should have just as much access to it as the OP. @Ratchet is right, talk to him and reach a compromise. Also, 72? Really? That's a bit much.

Comment: Set it for 68F and call it a day. Why 72F? That's tropical weather.

Comment: Waiting for the companion question: How do I keep my roommate from overheating the house and wasting lots of MY utility money on making the house uncomfortably hot?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a social problem, not a home improvement problem.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comments about this being something you need to work out as people rather than trying to slap a technological fix on... if this really matters to you, you could offer to pay the heating bill out of your own pocket, or to pay a larger share of it, since you're the one who wants to spend more on fuel.